# c# winforms How do I use async await using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous, async-await

I want to use async await function to group by age. It's working fine without aync await, but I want
use asyn await.
If I exclude ToList() in firstline ...from u in db.Patient.ToList()... then I get problem with CalculateAge function
with error LINQ Entities does not recognize in the method CalculateAge(system.String)....
That's why use it there. 
CalculateAge function is to calculate age and here is code function

```
private int CalculateAge(string birthday)
        {
            int age;
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(birthday)) return 0;

            DateTime empBirthday = Convert.ToDateTime(birthday);
            DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
            age = today.Year - empBirthday.Year;
            if (empBirthday > today.AddYears(-age))
                age--;
            return age;
        }
```

This work fine without async await

```
private void btnByAge_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var result = (from u in db.Patient.ToList() // 
                  join a in db.Analys on u.PatientId equals a.PatientId
                  where a.Status == Active
                  group u by CalculateAge(u.DOB.ToString()) into g
                  select new
                  {
                      Age = g.Key,
                      Amount = g.Count(),
                  }).Tolist();

    if (result != null)
    {
        dgvResult.DataSource = result;
    }
}
```

But not this with async await

```
private async void btnByAge_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var result = (from u in db.Patient.ToListAsync()
                  join a in db.Analys on u.PatientId equals a.PatientId
                  where a.Status == Active
                  group u by CalculateAge(u.DOB.ToString()) into g
                  select new
                  {
                      Age = g.Key,
                      Amount = g.Count(),
                  });

    var data = await result.ToListAsync();
    if (data != null)
    {
        dgvResult.DataSource = data;
    }
}
```

Error I get is Error    CS1936  Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'Task>'.  'Join' not found... 
I have used even Using.System.Data.Linq , but the same problem. Please Help, thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to await the call to `db.Patient.ToListAsync()`.  Better yet do the join and where filter on the DB, then call `AsEnumerable` so you can call `CalculateAge` in the group by.  Or even better translate whatever `CalculateAge` does into code that can be translated to SQL.

Comment: @juharr Thank you for your response, but I'am new for this kind of staf, can you please show me by coding what exact you mean?

Comment: What does `CalculateAge` do ? Can you provide the implemenatation of it ?

Comment: Also it's very odd that `CalculateAge` takes a `string` instead of a `DateTime`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do to fix the error is to put an `await` before the `db.Patient.ToListAsync()`.  However it would be better to not even do that `ToList` so that the join can be done in the DB.  Also note you don't need the `null` check as the results will never be `null` (maybe empty or maybe an exception will be thrown, but they should never be null)

```
var dobs = await (from u in db.Patient
                  join a in db.Analys on u.PatientId equals a.PatientId
                  where a.Status == Active
                  select u.DOB).ToListAsync();
var data = dobs
    .GroupBy(x => CalculateAge(x.toString())
    .Select(grp => new
    {
        Age = grp.Key,
        Amount = grp.Count(),
    })
    .ToList();

dgvResult.DataSource = data;
```

That will do the join and filter on Status and select the DOBs in the DB and get the dobs asynchronously.  Then you can do the group by in memory since `CalculateAge` cannot be translated to SQL.  But an even better idea is to do the age calculation in the DB.

```
var now = DateTime.UtcNow(); // or .Now() if you don't store UTC in the DB
var result =  from u in db.Patient
              join a in db.Analys on u.PatientId equals a.PatientId
              where a.Status == Active
              let age = now.Year - u.DOB.Year -
                  ((u.DOB.Month < now.Month || 
                      (u.DOB.Month == now.Month && u.DOB.Day < now.Day))
                  ? 1 : 0)
              group u by age into g
              select new
              {
                  Age = g.Key,
                  Amount = g.Count(),
              };

dgvResult.DataSource = await result.ToListAsync();
```

That determines the age by subtracting the DOB year from the current year and then subtracting 1 if the current day is before the Month and Day of the DOB.

Also if you plan to use `CalculateAge` then just pass the `DateTime` to it instead of formatting it to a `string` and then parsing that back to a `DateTime`.  You can pass a `DateTime?` if it's possible that it might be `null`.

```
private int CalculateAge(DateTime? birthday)
{
    int age;
    if (!birthday.HasValue) return 0;

    DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
    age = today.Year - birthday.Value.Year;
    if (birthday.Value > today.AddYears(-age))
        age--;
    return age;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response. CalculateAge is calculation age, I have now edited my orginal post with CalculateAge function, how ever your solution seems better how to calculate age, but I get error Error CS0019 Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'bool' , I thing somewhere is conflicting between int  and bool here  now.Year - u.DOB.Value.Year - (u.DOB.Value.Month < now.Month || (u.DOB.Value.Month == now.Month && u.DOB.Value.Day < now.Day)). Can you please  check it again?

Comment: Yeah it needed one more set of parenthesis.

Comment: wonderful, it's working now perfect. Thank you very much , and even thank you all of you guys for your response

Comment: sorry Juharr for disturbing, But I prefer to use your first solution with 
function  CaluculationAge, but I get error here   var data = await result.ToListAsync(); It's result I'am geting error like IEnumerable<<anonymous type: int Age, int Amount>>' does not contain a definition for 'ToListAsync' and the best extension method overload 'QueryableExtensions.ToListAsync(IQueryable)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable'

Comment: I've updated the first one.  You have to do the `ToListAsync` instead of `AsEnumerable`  and then you don't need the null check as it will never be null.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing special  you can achieve this code in C#,look at below code.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var query = (from p in db.Patient
                     join An in db.Analys on p.PatientId equals An.PatientId
                     where An.Status == Active
                     select p.DOB)



       var Result=await query.GroupBy(x => CalculateAge(x.toString())
           .Select(g => new {
               Age = g.Key,
               Amount = g.Count(),
           }).ToListAsync();
 dgvResult.DataSource = Result
    }
```